# CSS: nav element jumping to a new line

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to build a website, where part of my code, contains a quote segment, and the idea is that I want some social links on the right side of it.

Unfortunately, my social links jumps to a line below my quote segment, instead of being on the same line, and I'm not sure why.

Heres my HTML:

```
<div class="quote--bar">
<div class="quote">
"To create an environment in which knowledge <br />
about information and its sphere can be obtained"
</div>
<nav class="socialImageContainer">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="logos twitterLogo"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="logos instagramLogo"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="logos facebookLogo"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="logos tumblrLogo"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="logos linkedInLogo"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And my LESS:

```
.quote--bar {
 padding-top: 20px;
 background: @BGColor2;
 display: inline-block;
 .quote {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  color: @TXTColor2;
 }
}
.socialImageContainer {
 .logos {
  margin: 20px 0;
  float: right;
  width: 51px;
  height: 51px;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

If you have any idea what I might be doing wrong, it would be very much appreciated!

Comment: It's either because you're using float instead of display and the element containing the quote has a lower X value on the screen or because you didn't define a width for .quote's CSS and it is hogging the entire row pushing the next element down.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand what you mean.. How would I go about changing my float to display? 

I'm also not sure about the second part of your tip - It sounds about right, but can you elaborate a bit on it?

Comment: I think in this case float might not be the problem and it's just that the default width for .quote is 100%.  So in .quote add `width: 30%;` or something like that until it looks good.  Basically, the two elements you want on the same row have to have a combined width that is less than the parent container's width.  Even though you don't see the extra width, it is there extended beyond the length of the text to the "right wall".

Comment: I get what you are saying, I actually tried lowering width of the socialImageContainer to 35%, and the .quote to 20%, but they are still on different lines - I even tried combining it with setting the quote--bar to 1000px, just to test, but doesn't change anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nav` and `div` have `display:block` by default, so the nav will display below the preceding div.

You probably meant to float the nav instead of the links inside it. In addition, the preceding div will also need to be either `display:inline-block` or `float:left`.

```css
.quote--bar {
 padding-top: 20px;
 background: @BGColor2;
 display: inline-block;
 .quote {
  float: left; /* <-- this one */
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  color: @TXTColor2;
 }
}
.socialImageContainer {
  float: right; /* <-- and this one */
  .logos {
   margin: 20px 0;
   width: 51px;
   height: 51px;
 }
 ul {
   list-style: none;
 }
 li {
   display: inline-block;
 }
}
```

Comment: I see your point - I tried changing it, but now my socialImageContainer just isn't getting displayed anywhere :S

Comment: @HowDoiJava Sorry, I pressed "post" too soon. Is this better?

Comment: You are a god! Thank you so much! I had to do a little fiddling around myself too, but now it works like a charm :)